# Is there a subtle difference in meaning between "the reference is -to- Jill's car" and "the reference is Jill's car"?

Tags: meaning

> Anaphora is the relation between an anaphor and an antecedent, as in
> *Jill has left her car in the road*, in the interpretation where the
> reference is to Jill’s car.

Does "the reference is to Jill’s car" have the same meaning as "the reference is Jill’s car"? What does 'to' function as?

Comment: I’ll let someone else elaborate, but the short answer is it’s part of the verbal phrase “refer to.“

Comment: I assume you can detect a difference between "the sign is a tree" and "the sign is to a tree"? The former describes the sign, the latter what it points to.

Comment: 'Jill has left her car in the road' **refers to** Jill's car. 'The reference is Jill's car' makes no sense.

Comment: *The **referent** is Jill's car.* No problemo. But it's difficult if not impossible to contrive a context where ***reference*** could work. Except *just maybe* someone's taking the idea that "prepositions aren't important" a little too far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved by understanding the words *refer* and *reference*. The verb [*refer*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/refer) makes a connection between two things. It's often used phrasally with "to": "My doctor *referred* me *to* a specialist"; "My sarcastic comment was *referring to* your appearance."

The noun *reference* can be used with or without the "to," but the meaning changes. Let's think of some of the times the "to" can be left out:

> Here are my *references* (letters from former employers that recommend me)
> At the end of my essay are all my *references* (listings of the other works that I quoted or learned from)

But I could pick out one particular reference in my essay and use "to": "This is a *reference to* the book *Snowglobes Through the Ages*." If we think of "reference" as a connection between two things—like an electrical wire—then we can use it without "to" when we're talking about the connection itself (the "wire"), *not about* what it connects to. (See? I just had to use "to" in that sentence!)

So in this case the author uses "to" in "the reference is to Jill's car" because the car is the thing *referred to*, the thing at the end of the connection. The car is not "a reference," the act of referring.

Comment: Reading through my answer, I see problems with it. Yes, in an essay we do use the word "references" not just for the act of referring but for "what it connects to," calling the bibliography a "list of references." And, confusingly, when I get letters of reference, I can call the people who *referred me* my "references"! Oh well—suffice it to say that these are idiomatic uses for these specific situations, and cars are not usually "references."

Comment: But [*the **referent** is a car*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22referent+is+a+car%22) certainly occurs a good few times in written contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hehe, twice I considered mentioning "referent" but decided not to complicate things.

Comment: Until this question came up, I'd never consciously made the connection between ***refer, reference, referent, referral,...*** and a ***referee*** (which normally puts me in mind of a sports "umpire", but OED includes the *legal* definition *A person to whom a dispute between parties is referred by mutual consent; an **arbitrator***).